# Tmux somehow forgets prefix after certain key-bind

Tags: tmux, urxvt, rxvt

I did not change default prefix i.e. `C-b`. I added the following key binding in my tmux.conf

```
bind -n C-M-w send-keys M-w\; \
    run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

Basically I wanted that during the copy mode `C-b [` I should be able to copy `save-buffer` to the clipboard as well. It works well but only for the first time. And after it is been executed once, it somehow magically unbinds the `prefix` and other key-bindings as well. I'm not sure why it does that.

I've fairly simple tmux config as below:

```
# 0 is too far from ` ;)
set -g base-index 1

# Automatically set window title
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g set-titles on

#set -g default-terminal screen-256color
set -g status-keys vi
set -g history-limit 10000

setw -g mode-keys emacs
setw -g mode-mouse on
setw -g monitor-activity on

bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key s split-window -v

bind-key J resize-pane -D 5
bind-key K resize-pane -U 5
bind-key H resize-pane -L 5
bind-key L resize-pane -R 5

bind-key M-j resize-pane -D
bind-key M-k resize-pane -U
bind-key M-h resize-pane -L
bind-key M-l resize-pane -R

# Use Alt-vim keys without prefix key to switch panes
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
bind -n M-j select-pane -D 
bind -n M-k select-pane -U
bind -n M-l select-pane -R

# Use Alt-arrow keys without prefix key to switch panes
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# Shift arrow to switch windows
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window

bind -n C-M-w send-keys M-w\; \
     run-shell "tmux save-buffer -  | xclip -i -selection clipboard"\; \
     set -g prefix 'C-b'

# No delay for escape key press
set -sg escape-time 0

# Reload tmux config
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace

```
bind -n C-M-w send-keys M-w\; \
     run-shell "tmux save-buffer -  | xclip -i -selection clipboard"\; \
     set -g prefix 'C-b
```

with

```
bind -n C-M-w send-keys M-w\; \
     run-shell "tmux save-buffer -  | xclip -i -selection clipboard >> /dev/null "\; \
     set -g prefix 'C-b
```

After playing around this issue [Thanks to Severyn Kozak](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140828)  who suggest using /dev/null

I think the problem in some commands that don't return output or exit status like xclip so redirecting the output to [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) will be enough for copying from paste buffer to clipboard.

I couldn't get why you use Send keys and set prefix commands ,but for tmux 1.8+ you should use copy-pipe command instead to copy selected text to paste buffer and clipboard

Copy and paste method using emacs-mode [from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72340):

```
bind-key -n -t emacs-copy M-w copy-pipe "xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c "
bind-key -n C-y run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

Using vi mode "prefix C-[ to enter copy mode >> v to highlight text >> y to copy text to both paste buffer and clipboard >> prefix p to paste ":

```
set -g mode-keys vi
bind -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe "xclip -i -sel clip"
bind p paste-buffer
```